# Display list of objects

Tags: java, list, jlist

I've got a list of objects of type Catalog. the class `Catalog` has a method called `getName` which returns the name of the object.
I've got `List<Catalogue> catalogList = /*code to retrieve list*/`

I tried this but it did not work

```
JList  jlist = new JList(catalogList.toArray());
```

My question is how do I display the names in a Jlist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the toString() method in your Catalogue class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getName();        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JList contains instances of `Catalog`. By default, it uses the `toString()` method of the objects it contains to display them. So your first option is to override `toString()` in Catalog and make it return the name.

Another, more general and flexible option is to set a custom cell renderer, which the list will call to display every Catalog object. The Swing tutorial has [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer).

Answer (score 0):

You want your jlist to have only the names of the elements from catalogList? as I see you're trying to add Catalogue elements to the Jlist

```
JList  jlist = new JList();
for(int i=0;i<catalogList.size();i++){
     jlist.add(catalogList.get(i).getName();
}
```

Might be a more efficient way then this, but I think this is easier to understand